# Is there an elegant way to determine if a file exists in/under runtimepath?

Tags: filesystem

I wonder if there is an elegant way to determine if a specific file exists in/under one of the entries of `&rtp`.

Currently, I use the following construct:

```
let s:found_ = 0
for s:dir_ in split(&rtp, ',')
  let s:file_ = s:dir_ . '/autoload/FooBarBaz.vim'
  if filereadable(s:file_)
     let s:found_ = 1
     break
  endif
endfor

if s:found_
   call FooBarBaz#func()
endif
```

I am under the impression that vim could offer a function or something that does it more elegantly, such as `exists('*FooBarBaz#func')` which unfortunately didn't work as I intended.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for `globpath()`. If it returns a non empty string, then there is at least a match.

```
if !empty((globpath(&rtp, '/autoload/FooBarBaz.vim'))
```

You may also want to check `filereadable()` if you suspect you may not be able to open the file. BTW, I'd have used `filter()` in your solution (I hate debugging vim loops) -> `if !empty(filter(split(&rtp,','), 'filereable(v:val."autoload/FooBarBaz.vim")')`

But in that case, I often simply run a:

```
runtime autoload/FooBarBaz.vim
if !exists('*FooBarBaz#func')
```

(See my convoluted [`lh#dev#option#call()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev/blob/master/autoload/lh/dev/option.vim#L73) which searches the first function that matches `prefix#{filetype}#postfix(args)` among a list of filetypes.)